# Open another page/content in another div HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need your help again.
I have 2 divs : sidebar and content. In SIDEBAR I have some links (a b c), When I press an "a" link I want to open pageA.html in CONTENT div, when I press "b" link - pageB.html and so on.
I tried whit iframe but i know it's not a great idea, any suggestions folks?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what we did in the nineties, it's called framesets, good luck with that.

Comment: whenever you want to display webpage inside another webpage, you must use iframe. You don't even need JS for this. what is the problem with iframe?

Comment: These days most people would use ajax and content replacement in the DOM, but whatever floats your goat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's load() function. It'll do just just what you're looking for without Angular or framesets.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

**HTML**

```
<h1>My Website</h1>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="nav_a" href="#">Page A</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_b" href="#">Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">Here's some default content (maybe Page A?)</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav_a").on("click", function(){
        $("#content").load("pageA.html");  
    });
    $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
        $("#content").load("pageB.html");  
    });    
});
```

Note that you won't be able to load pages outside of your domain, but it doesn't sound like you're trying to do that.

Comment: It is always import to mention or include what need to be imported before using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of approaching this. I would recommend using AngularJS. It may seem daunting at first, but it'll be worth it and can achieve what you want very easily.

```
<!-- include angular -->
<script src="angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">

  <!-- sidebar -->
  <a ng-click="template = 'page1.html'">Page One</a>
  <a ng-click="template = 'page2.html'">Page Two</a>

  <!-- content -->
  <div ng-include="template"></div>

</div>

<script>
  // define angular app
  angular.module('app', []);

  // define controller
  function main ($scope) {

    // instantiate template to show page one by default  
    $scope.template = 'page1.html';
  }

  // register controller
  angular.module('app').controller('main', main);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content from pageA.html can live on the main HTML page instead, you could just use JavaScript to show/hide divs when the related links are clicked.

If the content needs to live on individual HTML pages, then setting the src on an iframe using JS is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple jQuery get with Ajax is easiest. I am on my phone but this is a few lines of code as long as you are using jQuery:

$.get("url-of-content.htm",
            "",
             function(data){
               $("#CONTENT").html(data);
             );

Sorry i didn't provide more logic for retrieving dynamically the html content but I hope this helps as I have used this approach a lot with sites that already load jQuery because it is so easy to pull external content this way.

Comment: I will 2nd #mikehomme for the beyter jQuery answer!